# Find Volume V bounded by surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\sqrt[3]{ x^2}+\sqrt[3]{ y^2}+\sqrt[3]{ z^2}=1$

I try this substitution $x={u}^3$,$y={v}^3$ and $z={k}^3$ ,and I get sphere with radius 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=r\sin^3\alpha\cos^3\beta$, $y=r\sin^3\alpha\sin^3\beta$ 
 and $z=r\cos^3\alpha$.

Thus, $J=9r^2\sin^5\alpha\cos^2\alpha\sin^2\beta\cos^2\beta$ and the volume it's
$$9\int_{0}^1r^2dr\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^5\alpha\cos^2\alpha d\alpha\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^2\beta\cos^2\beta d\beta=\frac{4\pi}{35}$$
About Jacobian see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

Comment: Can you explain how to pick a substitution,I know solve when I know substitution,but I  dont know to pick. Thanks for solution.

Comment: Than you a lot,I find also general spherical coordinates,its much easier